# Chrome multiple window.open with mailto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've a website with a table of contacts and a button.
When the button gets clicked i want to open a mail client for each selected contact. 
But at least in the chrome webbrowser only the first `window.open()` is firing. The problem is already known that chrome does support only one `window.open()` with one user action (button click).

But isn't there a workaround?

```
function openMail(){
    let selected = $("#table").bootstrapTable("getSelections");
    for (let row of selected) {
         window.open(`mailto:${row.email}?subject=${row.bsubject}&body=${row.body}`, '_self');
    }
}
```

Comment: It is restricted for some good enough reason. The only way i know would involve using any third party plugin as flash BUT you would better for sure to rethink your design forcing user to click for opening each new tab

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter of window.open is the name of window. You have to assign a unique name (e.g. the number of row) instead of `_self`

```
    var roworder=0;
        for (let row of selected) {
           roworder++;
           window.open(`mailto:${row.email}?subject=${row.bsubject}&body=${row.body}`,
 'prefix-'+roworder);
    }
```

Comment: At least it opens the tabs - but only one mail client.... and not two,three...
so doen't work -.-